# Django: display/edit form depending on whether user is authenticated?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in Django. If the user is authenticated, I want them to see a form that they can edit: if they aren't, then I would like them to see a display-only form.

In both cases, I want to show the same information, just that if they are authenticated then I want the form to be editable.

Is there an easy way to do this in Django? I can check user.is_authenticated either in the template or in the view: what I don't want to do is duplicate form code in the template.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906994/using-django-forms-to-display-and-edit), but the accepted answer looks insanely complicated. Surely there must be something inbuilt in Django to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   {{form.as_table}}
{% else %}
   {% for field_name, value in form.data.iteritems %}
       {{field_name}}: {{value}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```